# Python pass enter key to subprocess.run function to exit from the process

Tags: python, csv, subprocess

I am trying to pass list of log files one by one to decoder exe to get csv file, below is the code -

```
p = subprocess.run(["wine", DECODER_EXE_PATH, str(decompressed_file_path)], capture_output=True, text=True)
```

The issue I am facing is that after every file the decoder exe is expecting to press/pass enter key otherwise, after decoding first file the process is getting stuck.
How can we achieve this in python script ?
Also, if I drag-drop the log file to decoder directly in windows, command prompt is showing like below after decoding the file -

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this works but you can try to add `input='\n' * 10` or so as argument to the `run` call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Michael..it's working now after adding **input='\n' * 10**